# About textbox events

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys I want to call a javascript function "ontextchange" event of text-box.
Following is my inline code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOutCardID" runat="server" Width="90%"
     OnTextChanged="javascript:GetOutgoingEmpDetail(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to pass text-box value to javascript function.
Is the above code right.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code? I think you have forgot  it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write on `onchange` instead of `OnTextChanged`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOutCardID" runat="server" Width="90%"
     onchange="javascript:GetOutgoingEmpDetail(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

It is a server side method [detail about the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange event for any input controls in javascript.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOutCardID" runat="server" Width="90%"
     onchange="return GetOutgoingEmpDetail(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```